# Program execution varies as the I/P size increases beyond 5 in C

Tags: c

This is the question.

For two strings A and B, we define the similarity of the strings to be the length of the longest prefix common to both strings. For example, the similarity of strings "abc" and "abd" is 2, while the similarity of strings "aaa" and "aaab" is 3.
Calculate the sum of similarities of a string S with each of it's suffixes.

**Input:**
The first line contains the number of test cases T. Each of the next T lines contains a string each.

**Output:**
Output T lines containing the answer for the corresponding test case.

**Constraints:**
1 <= T <= 10
The length of each string is at most 100000 and contains only lower case characters.

**Sample Input:**
2
ababaa
aa

**Sample Output:**
11
3

**Explanation:**
For the first case, the suffixes of the string are "ababaa", "babaa", "abaa", "baa", "aa" and "a". The similarities of each of these strings with the string "ababaa" are 6,0,3,0,1,1 respectively. Thus the answer is 6 + 0 + 3 + 0 + 1 + 1 = 11.

**The problem that I am facing :**
It is working correctly for test cases less than 5. For 5 and beyond 5, the output for the first string is printed as 0. For debugging, I used a character variable k to find the value pointed by the pointers. k had the values -54, -56 and other values when calculating for the first string. It is working correctly for other strings except the first one.

I even tried printing the first string. Some garbage value is being printed. But it is printing correctly for test cases < 5. I have given the code below. Please help me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int test_cases,i,j,*count;
    char k; //for testing purpose to determine the character at each iteration
    scanf("%d",&test_cases);
    count = calloc(test_cases,sizeof(int));
    char **strings, *initial_ptr, *current_ptr, *start_ptr;
    strings =  malloc(test_cases);
    for(i=0;i<test_cases;i++)
    {
       strings[i] =  malloc(100000);
       scanf("%s",strings[i]);
    }
    initial_ptr = start_ptr = *strings;
    current_ptr = *strings;

    //testing
    printf("This is the first string: ");
    puts(strings[0]);



    int temp_count=0;
    for(i=0;i<test_cases;i++)
    {
       current_ptr = initial_ptr = start_ptr = *(strings+i);
       temp_count=0;
       for(j=0;j<strlen(strings[i]);j++)
       {
         k = *current_ptr;
         while((*current_ptr) && (*current_ptr >= 'a') && (*current_ptr <= 'z'))
         {
           if(*current_ptr == *initial_ptr)
           {

             temp_count++;
             current_ptr++;
             initial_ptr++;
           }
           else
           {
             start_ptr++;
             current_ptr = start_ptr ;
             initial_ptr = *(strings+i) ;
           }
         }
         current_ptr = start_ptr;
         count[i]=temp_count;

       }
    }
    for(i=0;i<test_cases;i++)
    {
     printf("\n%d",count[i]);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You **must** absolutely mark your question as "homework" if it is.

Comment: Please fix your code indentation; it's very difficult to read.

Comment: calloc (x*y, 0) makes no sense to me.

Comment: 1) don't cast malloc. 2) don't put strlen() in the middle part of a for-loop. 3) learn about associativity and avoid excess (). 4) use 'a' and 'z' for character constants. 5) avoid long functions, divide your progam into functions. 6) use argv[] and stdin to get input for programs to avoid needing scanf() or opening files.

Comment: @ Kerrek SB  It is not a homework. I saw this question in a coding event

Comment: @wildplasser 

Removed casting in malloc. Used 'a' and 'z' instead of ASCII values I have to upload this solution to an online compiler. So I have to use scanf()

Comment: If you are working it as a learning exercise it is [homework] even if it is not "homework". The problem certainly has that contrived, "let give'm something goofy to test their skills" feel to it.

Comment: The problem statement, with input and output format, looks like it's an SPOJ, codechef or similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
count = (int *)calloc(test_cases*sizeof(int),0);
```

makes no sense. The second parameter in `calloc` is the size of the elements you're allocating. That call should read:

```
count = calloc(test_cases, sizeof(int));
```

This one is wrong too:

```
strings = (char **) malloc(test_cases);
```

should be:

```
strings = malloc(test_cases*sizeof(char*));
```

This:

```
printf("This is the first string: ");
puts(strings[1]);
```

is misleading: it prints the *second* string.

Comment: Hey sorry, I was trying to change a lot of things while trying to debug. As you said, it should be puts(strings[0]); 

What is wrong in returning a character pointer in malloc?

I made the changes you mentioned and still having the same problem.

Comment: What's wrong in your malloc and calloc calls is the amount of memory you're requesting. The casts are not required (nor recommended) in C.

Comment: @KiranKumar: and after the changes I suggest, your code _does_ behave as expected with an input of 10 lines (your example repeated five times)

Comment: I had edited the code in the post. It still behaves the same for me. I guess something is wrong with the value stored in strings[0].

Try printing strings[0]

Comment: I did. Please re-read my answer, your `malloc` call is still wrong.

Comment: Silly mistake.. Thanks a lot. It is working correctly now. :) Any idea on how to reduce complexity?