# Is this algorithm linear?

Tags: c, algorithm, big-o

Inspired by these two questions: [String manipulation: calculate the "similarity of a string with its suffixes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525692/string-manipulation-calculate-the-similarity-of-a-string-with-its-suffixes) and [Program execution varies as the I/P size increases beyond 5 in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552101/program-execution-varies-as-the-i-p-size-increases-beyond-5-in-c), I came up with the below algorithm.

The questions will be

1. Is it correct, or have I made a mistake in my reasoning?
2. What is the worst case complexity of the algorithm?

A bit of context first. For two strings, define their similarity as the length of the longest common prefix of the two. The total self-similarity of a string *s* is the sum of the similarities of *s* with all of its suffixes. So for example, the total self-similarity of *abacab* is 6 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 2 + 0 = 9 and the total self-similarity of *a* repeated `n` times is `n*(n+1)/2`.

**Description of the algorithm:** The algorithm is based on the Knuth-Morris-Pratt string searching algorithm, in that the *borders* of the string's prefixes play the central role.

To recapitulate: a *border* of a string *s* is a proper substring *b* of *s* which is simultaneously a prefix and a suffix of *s*.

Remark: If *b* and *c* are borders of *s* with *b* shorter than *c*, then *b* is also a border of *c*, and conversely, every border of *c* is also a border of *s*.

Let *s* be a string of length *n* and *p* be a prefix of *s* with length *i*. We call a border *b* with width *k* of *p* *non-extensible* if either `i == n` or `s[i] != s[k]`, otherwise it's extensible (the length `k+1` prefix of *s* is then a border of the length `i+1` prefix of *s*).

Now, if the longest common prefix of *s* and the suffix starting with `s[i], i > 0`, has length *k*, the length *k* prefix of *s* is a non-extensible border of the length *i+k* prefix of *s*. It is a border because it's a common prefix of *s* and `s[i .. n-1]`, and if it were extensible, it wouldn't be the longest common prefix.

Conversely, every non-extensible border (of length *k*) of the length *i* prefix of *s* is the longest common prefix of *s* and the suffix starting with `s[i-k]`.

So we can calculate the total self-similarity of *s* by summing the lengths of all non-extensible borders of the length *i* prefixes of *s*, `1 <= i <= n`. To do that

1. Calculate the width of the widest borders of the prefixes by the standard KMP preprocessing step.
2. Calculate the width of the widest non-extensible borders of the prefixes.
3. For each *i*, `1 <= i <= n`, if `p = s[0 .. i-1]` has a non-empty non-extensible border, let *b* be the widest of these, add the width of *b* and for all non-empty borders *c* of *b*, if it is a non-extensible border of *p*, add its length.
4. Add the length *n* of *s*, since that isn't covered by the above.

**Code (C):**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 * Overflow and NULL checks omitted to not clutter the algorithm.
 */

int similarity(char *text){
    int *borders, *ne_borders, len = strlen(text), i, j, sim;
    borders = malloc((len+1)*sizeof(*borders));
    ne_borders = malloc((len+1)*sizeof(*ne_borders));
    i = 0;
    j = -1;
    borders[i] = j;
    ne_borders[i] = j;
    /*
     * Find the length of the widest borders of prefixes of text,
     * standard KMP way, O(len).
     */
    while(i < len){
        while(j >= 0 && text[i] != text[j]){
            j = borders[j];
        }
        ++i, ++j;
        borders[i] = j;
    }
    /*
     * For each prefix, find the length of its widest non-extensible
     * border, this part is also O(len).
     */
    for(i = 1; i <= len; ++i){
        j = borders[i];
        /*
         * If the widest border of the i-prefix has width j and is
         * extensible (text[i] == text[j]), the widest non-extensible
         * border of the i-prefix is the widest non-extensible border
         * of the j-prefix.
         */
        if (text[i] == text[j]){
            j = ne_borders[j];
        }
        ne_borders[i] = j;
    }
    /* The longest common prefix of text and text is text. */
    sim = len;
    for(i = len; i > 0; --i){
        /*
         * If a longest common prefix of text and one of its suffixes
         * ends right before text[i], it is a non-extensible border of
         * the i-prefix of text, and conversely, every non-extensible
         * border of the i-prefix is a longest common prefix of text
         * and one of its suffixes.
         *
         * So, if the i-prefix has any non-extensible border, we must
         * sum the lengths of all these. Starting from the widest
         * non-extensible border, we must check all of its non-empty
         * borders for extendibility.
         *
         * Can this introduce nonlinearity? How many extensible borders
         * shorter than the widest non-extensible border can a prefix have?
         */
        if ((j = ne_borders[i]) > 0){
            sim += j;
            while(j > 0){
                j = borders[j];
                if (text[i] != text[j]){
                    sim += j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    free(borders);
    free(ne_borders);
    return sim;
}


/* The naive algorithm for comparison */
int common_prefix(char *text, char *suffix){
    int c = 0;
    while(*suffix && *suffix++ == *text++) ++c;
    return c;
}

int naive_similarity(char *text){
    int len = (int)strlen(text);
    int i, sim = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        sim += common_prefix(text,text+i);
    }
    return sim;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < argc; ++i){
        printf("%d\n",similarity(argv[i]));
    }
    for(i = 1; i < argc; ++i){
        printf("%d\n",naive_similarity(argv[i]));
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So, is this correct? I'd be rather surprised if not, but I've been wrong before.

What is the worst case complexity of the algorithm?

I think it's O(n), but I haven't yet found a proof that the number of extensible borders a prefix can have contained in its widest non-extensible border is bounded (or rather, that the total number of such occurrences is O(n)).

I'm most interested in sharp bounds, but if you can prove that it's e.g. O(n*log n) or O(n^(1+x)) for small `x`, that's already good. (It's obviously at worst quadratic, so an answer of "It's O(n^2)" is only interesting if accompanied by an example for quadratic or near-quadratic behaviour.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm#Efficiency_of_the_search_algorithm

Comment: @HansPassant I'm doing something different with the borders table, I don't see how the reasoning for the KMP algorithm could be applied to that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Your question needs time to read details but why you didn't try check its running time with different inputs? related curve at least gives you an idea about the upper bound.

Comment: Have you tried running the program several times with random input data and plot the run times? I'm of course not saying that would give a complete and correct answer to your question, but it would probably give a general idea about how the run time changes in reataion to the size of the input.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri So far, I haven't found anything indicating nonlinear behaviour, but I'd like to have a proof or counterexample.

Comment: @Grigry Random input is linear, the only possibility for nonlinear behaviour is input with special regular patterns. I'm trying to find out if there are such patterns or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This looks like a really neat idea, but sadly I believe the worst case behaviour is O(n^2).

Here is my attempt at a counterexample.  (I'm not a mathematician so please forgive my use of Python instead of equations to express my ideas!)

Consider the string with 4K+1 symbols

```
s = 'a'*K+'X'+'a'*3*K
```

This will have

```
borders[1:] = range(K)*2+[K]*(2*K+1)

ne_borders[1:] = [-1]*(K-1)+[K-1]+[-1]*K+[K]*(2*K+1)
```

Note that:

1) ne_borders[i] will equal K for (2K+1) values of i.

2) for 0<=j<=K, borders[j]=j-1

3) the final loop in your algorithm will go into the inner loop with j==K for 2K+1 values of i

4) the inner loop will iterate K times to reduce j to 0

5) This results in the algorithm needing more than N*N/8 operations to do a worst case string of length N.

For example, for K=4 it goes round the inner loop 39 times

```
s = 'aaaaXaaaaaaaaaaaa'
borders[1:] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
ne_borders[1:] = [-1, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

For K=2,248 it goes round the inner loop 10,111,503 times!

Perhaps there is a way to fix the algorithm for this case?

Comment: Thanks for the example. Can you explain how you found it? I have only looked at more complicated inputs and always got confused trying to find one which produces nonlinear behaviour.

Comment: Nothing interesting to add I am afraid: I just brute forced all strings of length N containing symbols 'a' and 'X'.  I then chose a type of string which gave a large number of inner loops and looked simple enough that I would be able to work out a closed form solution for borders and ne_borders.

Comment: Ah, the power of brute force :-/

Answer (score 8):

You might want to have a look at the Z-algorithm, that's provably linear:

s is a C-string of length N

```
Z[0] = N;
int a = 0, b = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
{
  int k = i < b ? min(b - i, Z[i - a]) : 0;
  while (i + k < N && s[i + k] == s[k]) ++k;
    Z[i] = k;
  if (i + k > b) { a = i; b = i + k; }
}
```

Now similarity is just the sum of entries of Z.

Comment: Very cool, thanks (and +1) for that. Doesn't answer my question, though.

Comment: I know it is late, but can you please explain this amazing code or point me towards a source where I can learn better about the algorithm.