# Longest prefix string length for all the suffixes

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Find the length of the longest prefix string for all the suffixes of the string.

For example suffixes of the string `ababaa` are `ababaa`, `babaa`, `abaa`, `baa`, `aa` and `a`. The similarities of each of these strings with the string "ababaa" are 6,0,3,0,1,1 respectively. Thus the answer is 6 + 0 + 3 + 0 + 1 + 1 = 11.

I wrote following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ( int argc, char **argv) {
    size_t T;
    std::cin >> T;
    char input[100000];
    for ( register size_t i = 0; i < T; ++i) {
        std::cin >> input;

        double t = clock();

        size_t len    = strlen(input);
        char *left    = input;
        char *right   = input + len - 1;
        long long sol = 0;
        int end_count = 1;
        while ( left < right ) {
            if ( *right != '\0') {
                if ( *left++ == *right++ ) {
                    sol++;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            end_count++;
            left = input; // reset the left pointer
            right = input + len - end_count; // set right to one left.
        }
        std::cout << sol + len << std::endl;
        printf("time= %.3fs\n", (clock() - t) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
    }
}
```

Working fine, but for a string which is `100000` long and having same character i.e. `aaaaaaaaaa.......a`, it is taking long time , how can i optimize this one more.

Comment: That's an astonishingly common problem, it seems. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8568265/1011995) is an O(n) algorithm (disclaimer: I haven't verified the algorithm).

Answer (score 3):

You can use Suffix Array: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array

Comment: How? Looks to me like creating the suffix array would take longer (and use a lot more memory) than the algorithm above. Even after it's created, doesn't it increase the work as you're doing repeated binary searches to check for substrings, whereas the algorithm above is going directly to the candidate characters?  Maybe I'm wrong - have only thought about this for a minute or two - but some sample code would help establish that....

Comment: The array can be built in O(n log n ) time (sorry, I don't remember the details) - and you are doing it one time only, as a task preprocessing.  But this is worth it as usually you need to find the longest prefix many times on the same text and each such search will cost only O(m + log n).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your `ababaa` is a pattern P.
I think you could use the following algorithm:

1. Create a suffix automata for all possible suffixes of P.
2. Walk the automata using P as input, count edges traversed so far. For each accepting state of the automata add the current edge count to total sum. Walk the automata until you either reach the end of the input or there are no more edges to go through.
3. The total sum is the result.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Z` algorithm to calculate length of all substrings, which also prefixes in `O(n)` and then scan resulting array and sum its values.

Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-of-similarities-of-string-with-all-of-its-suffixes/

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you are using plain array to evaluate the suffix and though it may turn out to be efficient for some data set, it would fail to be efficient for some cases, such as the one you mentioned.

You would need to implement a **Prefix-Tree** or [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) like Data Structure. The code for those aren't straightforward, so if you are not familiar with them, I would suggest you read a little bit about them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether a Trie gives you much performance gain.. but I would certainly think about it.

The other idea I had is to try to compress your string. I didn't really think about it, just a crazy idea...

if you have a string like this: `ababaa` compress it maybe to: `abab2a`. Then you have to come up with a technique where you can use your algorithm with those strings. The advantage is you can then compare long strings `100000a` efficiently with each other. Or more importantly: you can calculate your sum very fast.

But again, I didn't think it through, maybe this is a very bad idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here a java implementation:

```
        // sprefix
        String s = "abababa";
        Vector<Integer>[] v = new Vector[s.length()];
        int sPrefix = s.length();
        v[0] = new Vector<Integer>();
        v[0].add(new Integer(0));
        for(int j = 1; j < s.length(); j++)
        {
            v[j] = new Vector<Integer>();
            v[j].add(new Integer(0));
            for(int k = 0; k < v[j - 1].size(); k++)
                if(s.charAt(j) == s.charAt(v[j - 1].get(k)))
                {
                    v[j].add(v[j - 1].get(k) + 1);
                    v[j - 1].set(k, 0);
                }
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < v.length; j++)
            for(int k = 0; k < v[j].size(); k++)
                sPrefix += v[j].get(k);

        System.out.println("Result = " + sPrefix);
```